# What does negative proportion mean in sharpe optimization model?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, sharpe-ratio, rebalancing

Using the last 20 days of market return and some stocks return I made sharpe optimial portfolio and following were the stock names and investment proportion to be made.

```
 StockName   InvProportion
   TATACHEM  -0.008707056
     COLPAL   0.076357499
  BATAINDIA   0.240493162
  NAVINFLUOR  -0.102407233
       ONGC   0.136215080
        IOC   0.658048548
```

I wanted to know if negative investment proportion or weight means I sell that stocks in that proportion?

And for how long can I hold this portfolio or when should I rebalance or liquidate and construct new portfolio?

Also will using just past 20 days return to construct portfolio will hold any water in short term say next 10 or 20 days or it is of no use and I should only use yearly returns or monthly returns to construct sharpe optimized portfolio?

Comment: "using just past 20 days" to estimate expected returns is completely useless for forming portfolios. Such estimates are merely noise. Use 20 *years* of data if you are going to rely on historical estimates.

Comment: @noob2 Is it okay if I use 10 years of data?

Comment: yes, you could use 10 years.

Comment: @noob2 what does negative weightage means? Do I need to sell that stock in that proportion? or we can ignore that security?

Comment: negative weight => you have to short (sell) that stock in proportion. If you don't want to short, you can add inequality constraints to keep the weights > 0

Comment: @noob2 Where do I add that constraint? In the sharpe optimization model no where such constraint is mentioned. Do you have example I can refer? Since short selling for more than 1 day for retailers is not possible in India.